# Subtitles are not displaying the when seek to backward in videoview

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, android-video-player

In my Android app videos are played with subtitles using videoview. The problem is when I'm pressing forward or dragging the seekbar subtitles are displaying, but when I'm pressing backward or dragging the seekbar backwards subtitles are not displaying. Below is the full code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener,MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener,MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener {
MediaController   ctlr;
VideoView videoview;
FrameLayout playercontrolerview;
View view_full_cc;
TextView tv_subtitleText;
private static Handler handler = new Handler();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    tv_subtitleText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitleText);
    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        setVideoView();
        preparedvideo();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void setVideoView() {
    ctlr = new MediaController(MainActivity.this) {
        @Override
        public void show() {
            repositionSubtitle(true);
            super.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void hide() {
            repositionSubtitle(false);
            super.hide();
        }
    };
    playercontrolerview = (FrameLayout) ctlr.getParent();
    ctlr.setMediaPlayer(videoview);
    ctlr.setAnchorView(videoview);
    videoview.setMediaController(ctlr);
    videoview.requestFocus();



}


private void preparedvideo(){

    videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.samplevideo));

    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            try {

                mp.addTimedTextSource(getSubtitleFile(R.raw.sub1), MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);

                int textTrackIndex = findTrackIndexFor(MediaPlayer.TrackInfo.MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_TIMEDTEXT, mp.getTrackInfo());

                if (textTrackIndex >= 0) {
                    try {
                        mp.selectTrack(textTrackIndex);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w("subtitles", "Cannot find text track!");
                }

                mp.setOnTimedTextListener(new MediaPlayer.OnTimedTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimedText(final MediaPlayer mp, final TimedText text) {
                        if(text!=null){
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        int seconds = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;

                                        Log.e("Subtitle", "subtitle Info " + text.getText());

                                        tv_subtitleText.setText(text.getText());
                                    }catch (Exception w){
                                        w.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            Log.e("Subtitle", "subtitle Info null ");
                        }

                    }
                });
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                videoview.start();

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



}

public void repositionSubtitle(boolean isShown) {

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) tv_subtitleText.getLayoutParams();
            if (params != null) {
                if (isShown)
                    params.bottomMargin = 150;
                else
                    params.bottomMargin = 0;

                tv_subtitleText.setLayoutParams(params);
            }


}

private int findTrackIndexFor(int mediaTrackType, MediaPlayer.TrackInfo[] trackInfo) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < trackInfo.length; i++) {
        if (trackInfo[i].getTrackType() == mediaTrackType) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
private String getSubtitleFile(int resId) {
    String fileName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resId);
    File subtitleFile = getFileStreamPath(fileName);
    if (subtitleFile.exists()) {
        Log.d("subtitle", "Subtitle already exists");
        return subtitleFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    Log.d("subtitle", "Subtitle does not exists, copy it from res/raw");

    // Copy the file from the res/raw folder to your app folder on the
    // device
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(resId);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(subtitleFile, false);
        copyFile(inputStream, outputStream);
        return subtitleFile.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeStreams(inputStream, outputStream);
    }
    return "";
}

private void copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int length = -1;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
}

// A handy method I use to close all the streams
private void closeStreams(Closeable... closeables) {
    if (closeables != null) {
        for (Closeable stream : closeables) {
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}




@Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    videoview.getCurrentPosition();

  //  Collection<Caption> subtitles = srt.captions.values();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {

}
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions (I have made this comment to you before).

Comment: Please refrain from adding begging messages Harish, especially once they have been taken out - that is just rude. They do not help anyway. If you are unhappy about these sorts of community edits, please flag for a moderator and appeal - however I would expect such a request to be rejected.